# Graphileon - Environment Variables

Tags: ajax, graphileon

We are using Graphileon in a Kubernetes pod as a docker container. Can we make use of environment variables for e.g.

```
var body = JSON.stringify({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/api",
                    method: "POST",
                    body: {key1 : <value>}
                })

$.ajax({
url: "/proxy",
method: "POST",
data: body
})
```

Can I get the < value > from a System environment variable from server side docker container?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible to use any server side values in the proxy call.